# WhatsApp Chat to Continue

Tags: whatsapp

We have discovered today that the WhatsApp's click to chat link is not working anymore.

For instance, if you visit https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=XXXXXX&text=hi, the browser shows a website with the following button.

[image]

But if you click "Continue to Chat", it prompts you to download WhatsApp on mobile device. Or if you were using desktop computer, it prompts you to login WhatsApp. Previously, it would go directly to the chat area.

Is there any workaround? Thank you.

Comment: It is working for me, and it is not happening as you said.

Comment: @turivishal thanks for your reply. It still won't get redirected to chat area, wrecking great havoc for our company.

Comment: try a few things, Try to update your browser to the latest version, try clearing the cache of your browser, login again in WhatsApp web, and check this link.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the underlying deep link instead of the URL. We do this in production and it works reliably.

The deep link is: `whatsapp://send?phone=1234&text=smth`. If you have any symbols in your message text, then you should URL encode it. For instance, if you're using JavaScript then you'd first run [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on your text. The phone umber should be written with the international country code included as a prefix.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But for my case we want to open WhatsApp from browser, not from iOS app.
We in Hong Kong have a lot of people reporting similar incidents. Don't know if other countries also experience this.

Comment: Makes sense. Then yes, this solution won’t work for you.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this problem suddenly too here in Austria. What worked for us:

1. Uninstall the WhatsApp-Client for Windows and download and install the latest Version
2. Use the Link-Variant provided by @pir with the phone number written with the International Country Code, e.g. `whatsapp://send?phone=43699123xxxxx`

This not only works in JavaScript but also in the URL-Searchbar of your Browser, you can use it like any other hyperlink.

Comment: seems to be working. Maybe we should do the WA redirection this way rather than the previous way.